# ASP.NET Core 2.0 IIS Web Hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, iis-10

I created an ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC Web Application and I need help getting it setup to run with IIS on Windows Server 2016.

So far, I have followed and completed all the steps on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis?tabs=aspnetcore2x up to the section **Application configuration**. This is the step that I'm stuck at and have not been able to complete the steps below it.

I'm going to post my Startup.cs and Program.cs code as to what I have now. I'm not sure if those two files need modified.

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<WinTenDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

Comment: What are you stuck with? Why are you unable to complete the steps?

Comment: @KirkLarkin, I'm not sure what else needs completed. How do I publish my Project in Visual Studio to IIS? Do I need to modify the Startup.cs and Program.cs files?

Comment: You shouldn't need to make any changes to either of those files. The steps in the publishing guide you linked should be all you need. Stack Overflow is for specific questions/problems so I encourage you to add more information about where you're struggling.

Comment: @KirkLarkin, When I publish using Visual Studio using the IIS option, this is the error i get. I get 65 other errors like this **"C:\Users\jdoe\source\repos\WinTenUpgradeSchedule\WinTenUpgradeSchedule\obj\Release\netcoreapp2.0\PubTmp\Out\wwwroot\lib\bootstrap\dist\fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff" to "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WinTenUpgradeSchedule\wwwroot\lib\bootstrap\dist\fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff". Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WinTenUpgradeSchedule\wwwroot\lib\bootstrap\dist\fonts' is denied**

Comment: Have you tried running Visual Studio as Administrator? You might not have permission to write to `C:\inetpub\wwwroot`...

Comment: @KirkLarkin, Yes, I was able to publish fine by right clicking on my project and choosing "Open folder in File Explorer". However, after I added my projects folder to IIS on my server I get an error when trying to access my application that is connected to the DB. I can access static files fine. The error is receive is **An error occurred while processing your request. Development Mode Swapping to Development environment will display more detailed information about the error that occurred.

Comment: You might missing write access to the folder on the IIS box. What you might try is to set up the website on your server box which includes the folder where your application goes. Then use Visual Studio to publish to a folder. You'll end up with your stuff in bin\Release\PublishOutput under your project folder. Just copy that stuff manually to the serve and things should work fine. Once you get that working circle back and figure out your permission problems with remote deployment to the IIS server.

Comment: @GlennSills, I've tried different permissions but still no luck. Do I need to make any changes to the Startup.cs file to use .IsProduction instead of .IsDevelopement?

Comment: Nope. There is no reason to change your startup. Do you have multiple appsettings files?

Comment: Did you add the hosting sdk to you server?

Comment: @GlennSills, No, I only have one App Settings which is .IsDevelopment. Yes, the hosting sdk was added.

Comment: When you deploy you won't be in development mode.

Comment: @GlennSills, I can load data from my db, but when I perform CRUD operations. I get this error. **An error occurred while processing your request. Development Mode Swapping to Development environment will display more detailed information about the error that occurred. Development environment should not be enabled in deployed applications, as it can result in sensitive information from exceptions being displayed to end users. For local debugging, development environment can be enabled by setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to Development, and restarting the application.**

Answer (score 0):

The issue that I was having I finally figured it out. It had to do with the account that was setup for me on the Domain that was added to the Security on the SQL Server. Once I provided the correct permissions to that AD account I no longer received the error messages.